# Chrome shows CORS error for GCS but file gets uploaded

Tags: google-chrome, cors, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a file to GCS by making a `PUT` request to a signed URL.
The CORS configuration of my bucket is

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
    "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

This is the response of preflight
[image]

But chrome shows CORS error in console while making the actual PUT request.
[image]

Now the interesting part is that the file is actually getting uploaded to the bucket!

I am confused as to what exactly is happening here and why is chrome showing CORS error in the console when the file upload is working correctly.

Comment: Evidently, the _preflight_ request itself is successful and the browser does send the _actual_ request; therefore, your file gets successfully uploaded. The CORS issue you observe is caused by the response to the _actual_ request, which lacks an appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: Also: [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I think your origin is misconfigured.

Try :

```
"origin":"*",
```

Comment: Hi Ronnie, this also gives the same behaviour.

Comment: try your original configuration but remove the port number ? the `:3000` part ?